# Inserting data into from Html form to MySQL Database using Python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have a form like this:

```
<form onSubmit = "return checkPassword(this)" action="C:\Users\Saksham\Desktop\Connection\connection.py" method="POST">
  
<label>
Name
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="">
</label>
<label>
Email-ID
<input type="email" id="email" name="email"pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$"; required placeholder="">
</label>
<label>
Password
<input type="password" id="password1" name = password1 required placeholder="">
</label>
<label>
Confirm Password
<input type="password" id="password2" name = password2 required placeholder="">
</label>
<label>
Date of Birth:
<input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday" required placeholder="">
</label>


<button  style="background-color:#3e3939";type="submit"; class="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

And My connection.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask 
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL 
mysql = MySQL() 
app=Flask(__name__) 
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] ="root" 
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = "password"
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] ="db_name" 
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = "localhost" 
mysql.init_app(app) 
con=mysql.connect() 
cursor=con.cursor() 
@app.route('/register',methods=['POST']) 
def register(): 
    name=request.form['name'] 
    email=request.form['email'] 
    password2=request.form['password2'] 
    birthday=request.form['birthday']
    cursor.execute("insert into table_name values (%s,%s,%s,%s)",       (name,email,password2,birthday)) 
    con.commit() 
    return "successfully registered"
```

Now I want the input in my html form to be inserted in the mysql database, When I execute this it just shows me the code on the browser, I have wasted over 10 days, finding the solution, but didn't got any!

Please help me!
Answers would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance :-)

EDIT:

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb86Z.png)

I get this when I add '/register' as the action

Comment: set the action properly! `action="C:\Users\Saksham\Desktop\Connection\connection.py"` this is just the path of the file. set it as `action="/register"` as you set the route by `@app.route('/register',methods=['POST'])`

Comment: But then how will it connect to the python file?

Comment: You write `@app.route('/register',methods=['POST'])` for a reason... It basically means any url which is like `/register` (after the domain name) will be routed to this function...

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the form like this:

```
<form onSubmit = "return checkPassword(this)" action="C:\Users\Saksham\Desktop\Connection\connection.py" method="POST">
```

You can't simply try to POST the form to a file on the filesystem - you need to POST it to the URL of the running Flask app. You need to run the Flask app first, eg on the command line:

```
export FLASK_APP=connection.py
flask run
```

(note that if you're using a production WSGI server it will be different, but one step at a time).
When the app runs, it will tell you the URL it's listening on, eg:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Use this URL as the base for your HTML POST URL, something like this:

```
<form onSubmit = "return checkPassword(this)" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/register" method="POST">
```

Comment: Just use a relative url instead of specifying the domain i.e. `action="/register"` your browser will automatically know what domain etc. to send the request to.

Comment: If you just use a relative URL, your browser may well not know the port that the Flask app is listening on, since the HTML seems to be in a different context - this is why I specified the full URL :-)